# Slice() doesn't display if array contains less then end number

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination

I made a pagination, but there is a problem about slicing the array. Let's say an `array` contains 20 `objects` inside it. And pagination displays all. 10 per page. The code is right below.

```
data(){
    return {
        perPage: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
        pageIndex: Number,
    };
},
computed: {        
    mainDatas() { 
        // other codes...
        //...

        this.pageIndex = this.currentPage * this.perPage;
        makeSort = makeSort.slice(this.pageIndex, this.pageIndex + this.perPage);

        return makeSort;
    },
}
```

But when I apply filter on the array. And let's say `array` now contains 17 objects. Then it's only show sliced first 10, the rest of 7 doesn't display. Next page is doesn't show up.

How can I make paginate without problem? What should I try...

Comment: You should not be setting any `data` property values (ie `this.pageIndex`) within a computed property function

Comment: Try `let pageIndex = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage`. Your issue is that you are starting at index `10` when on page 1 because `1 * 10 === 10`

Comment: thank you but, that is not problem solver.  if I do  `- 1` then yes it starts from 0 but, then I can't see the second third etc... becuse `currentPage` is being 0 and 0 x 10 = 0; in the end i can't get the next 10 ~ 20 or 30 ~ 40 items... @Phil

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't `currentPage` become `1`, `2`, etc when navigating pages?

Comment: oh, sorry. You were right I made a mistake somewhere else... Thank you. @Phil